# Agendar serviço no Azure

Tags: microsoft-azure

Ola, alguém sabe como faço para agendar a execução diária de um .exe no Azure? Tenho um notificador de email que precisa rodar todos os dias, é um projeto em C# que gera um executável e gostaria de colocar ele no Azure e deixar executando toda manhã.

Não tenho um VPS nem como deixar na minha máquina local pois não tenho como deixa-la ligada 24/7. Seria algo semelhante ao agendamento do windows.

Comment: Encontrei um post sobre serviços em background no Azure, vou testar e se funcionar coloco aqui: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui configurar seguindo o tutorial [aqui](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/).  Dentro dos Serviços de Aplicativos no Azure é só clicar em "Trabalhos Web" e preencher o seguinte formulário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele permite enviar o zip com o .exe e escolher a forma de disparo, no meu caso foi Agendado e a periodicidade é especificada com base em uma [expressão CRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), para executar todo dia as 6:30 da manhã:

```
0 30 6 * * *
```

Fiz dessa forma mas pode ser feito usando a interface do agendador do Azure:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O bacana é pode visualizar os logs também. Vi que ele permite também chamar outros tipos de arquivos: bat, js, py, cmd.